# Android Studio incorrectly saving password--adds extra characters

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, bundle

This seems to be caused by the latest version(s) of Android Studio, and occurs when I'm trying to generate a bundle. I'll have copied in the correct password, selected "save password", and it works fine. The next time I come in to build a bundle however, it's added more characters to the password fields (and not always evenly either), and the build will fail because of an incorrect password. Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

[image]